# Access PDF file from another project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two projects in eclipse `foo` and `bar`. `bar` is included as part of `foo` using the build path configuration in eclipse. This allows me to access all of the Java files i need from `bar` inside of `foo`.

However, I also have some PDF help documents which are contained inside of `bar`. These files are contained within a `help/` directory. When I try to access the files like this, `help/file.pdf`, it works in `bar`, but not `foo`.

How can I access these PDF files in `foo`?

**Q&A**

*How are files accessed?* Files are accessed by searching the class path for a resource. (i.e. `getClassLoader().getResource(path)`)

Comment: Try putting `help` in the build path, as source folder. The problem is that eclipse can link the folder, but the JVM doesn't know about that linking.

Comment: How do you acces the files? Are you accessing them via filesystem? If so, what exact path?

Comment: @rpax How do you add another projects directory as a source folder?

Comment: @rpax Trying a linked folder doesn't work because there is a folder with the same name.

Comment: Not as a source folder of project `foo`, as a source folder of project `bar`. Everything on `bar`'s build path is available to `foo` as a resource. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using 'Build Path' option in Eclipse IDE you set IDE to add path of 'bar' class files location in JVM class path i.e. 'bin'. And you can get any resource through these paths.

You will need a Class to get the resource because JVM returns resources by taking that class as reference.

Let `Anchor` be a class in `help` package of `bar` project.
Here is a code in a class in `foo` project.

```
URL url = bar.Anchor.class.getResource("file.pdf");
System.out.println(url);
```

You cannot get a resource directly (without taking a class as reference).
It is because JVM basically keep account of only .class files that are found in its path.

But if you still want to get the file without using any .class file as reference then it can be done by simply using File(location_of_file) class. It is simple method and I know you don't want this here.

If you wants to get the file only through path that you set by using 'Build Path', then you will need to check that file in the classpath of JVM.
To get the classpath you will need to call System.getProperty() method and get 'java.class.path' property. And then check all paths present in classpath.

```
File file = new File("help","file.pdf");   //'file.pdf' file in 'help' folder 
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(classpath,";");
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
    File temp = new File(tokenizer.nextToken(), file);
    if(temp.exists()){
        // here you get your file as 'temp'.
        // If you want it to be in URL form, you can convert it.
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Here is the directory structure used in example :
   |--`bar`  //project
   |   |--`bin` .... // created by IDE (its location is set in class path,
   |   |   |--.....      // and classes and resources are added by IDE)
   |   |
   |   |--`src`
   |      |--`help`
   |         |--`Anchor.java`
   |         |--`file.pdf`
   |
   |--`foo` //project
       |--`src`
          |--`Accessor.java`

---

Comment: What are the exact build path settings though? If you look at my question I essentially have your code.

Comment: In your case build path configuration should be set by adding **bar** project from **Project** tab in **Java Build Path** Option.

Comment: Do you still need my code to get my points? @screenmutt. I think it should be clear now.

Comment: I don't know what you are expecting here. I showed how you can get resource from other project by taking class of that another project as reference, told you that without taking class as reference it is impossible even in its own project. And also showed a method to get it by searching yourself in classpath. What now? @screenmutt

Comment: I have been searching the class path and it isn't working. I used your code almost exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have included `bar` as a part of `foo` using the *build bath* configuration in Eclipse, `bar` is in the build classpath when `foo` is compiled.

The correspondent built artifact for `bar` (e.g. a jar file) should be in the classpath at runtime too. To accomplish this you have to configure your deployment; doing this in Eclipse is different whith different type of projects. What type of project is `foo`?

Now, if you have a project in the classpath (build or runtime), you can find resources in it using a class loader.

Assuming you have *added the help folder as a source folder* in `bar` and you have a class `com.mycompany.MyClass` in `foo` , you can get the URL of your resource in `foo` using the following:

```
java.net.URL pdfUrl = com.mycompany.MyClass.class.getResource("/help/file.pdf");
```

Then, with that URL you can open a stream to read your resource:

```
java.io.InputStream is = url.openStream();
```

Comment: The does not appear to be working. The file is not found in the classpath.

Comment: Which part of this code is not working for you? If you run it in debugger, can you see pdfUrl with a value? And what about the input stream?

Comment: The file is not found on the classpath. pdfUrl is a null variable.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, `help` needs to be a Source folder of project bar. That way all of the contents of `help` will be copied to bar's output location and thus available to `foo`.